# Spring: How to Extract Data from One Object and Insert Into Another

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I currently have two tables: **Workforce** and **Employees**. The **Workforce** table is a collection of all potential employees who have submitted resumes to join the company. The **Employees** table is a collection of persons in the **Workforce** table that have actually been hired.

**Environment**:
1. Eclipse
2. Java (J2EE)
3. Maven
4. Spring
5. JPA (JpaRepository)

For brevity, I will stick to the files that are of concern for this extraction of data and insertion of data into another table.

Because of the similarities of both tables, many fields in the **Workforce** table will be similar to those in the **Employees** table:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Department
4. Phone Number
   etc...

If the person in the workforce is chosen, there is a boolean value called "isHired" that will have the value of 1. Every week, the person's in the **Workforce** table with values of "1" for "isHired" will be extracted from the Workforce table and inserted into the Employees table.

The general SQL Query looks something like this (and works in a regular IDE with no Spring HPQL constraints):

```
INSERT INTO Employees (firstName, lastName, dept, phone) 
SELECT emp_firstName, emp_lastName, emp_dept, emp_phone 
FROM Workforce WHERE isHired = 1
```

This works without a hitch, but we're talking about JPA, so this is what I have done:

In a Repository, the process has been broken into two items: 1) extracting data from one table (Workforce) and then 2) inserting extracted data into another table (Employees)

**WorkforceRepository.java**

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.entities.Workforce;

@Repository
public interface WorkforceRepository extends JpaRepository<Workforce, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new Workforce("
        + "w.workforceid, "
        + "w.firstName, "
        + "w.lastName, "
        + "w.dept, "
        + "w.phone) "
        + "FROM Workforce w WHERE isHired = 1")
    public List<Workforce> getNewHires();

}
```

**Workforce.java**

```
package com.example.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Generatedvalue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKFORCE")
public class Workforce implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Workforce() {
    }
    public Workforce(long workforceid, String firstName, lastName, dept, phone) {
    this.workforceid = workforceid;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.phone = phone;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="workforceid")
    private long workforceid;

    @Column(name="firstName)
    private String firstName;
    // OTHER DECLARATIONS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
}
```

**NOTE: I have left out the Employee.java and EmployeesRepository.java for BREVITY** They are pretty much the same and aside from the **employeeid**, that is the primary key for the Employee table, the other columns are exactly the same. The contructor class only contains the four columns that are the same as well.

I have a ton of CRUD operations that work, while the operations are only occurring within the same table. However, I would like to do this:

**EmployeesController.java**

```
// IMPORTS REMOVED FOR BREVITY
List<Workforce> retrievedRisks = Workforce.getNewHires();
for (Workforce w: retrievedRisks)
    Employees.saveAndFlush(w);
// MISC CODE REMOVED FOR BREVITY
```

The error I receive of course is below:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Workforce to Employees
```

Anyone know how to extract data from one POJO object and insert it into another using JpaRepository?

Comment: Why don't you just execute your SQL query? Anyway, what's the difficulty in doing just `new Employee(w.getFirstName(), w.getLastName(), ...)`?

Comment: @JBNizet The entire premise behind Spring/JPA is to save the programmer time by allowing the Framework to manipulate your data and that includes List objects. If not, I can just code raw SQL all day. If our team has to use Spring JPA, I'd like to master all of its functionality without using shortcuts or other methods. This example is actually over 100 columns long, not the 4 I have illustrated for brevity in this example. Therein lies the difficulty.

Comment: I use JPA every day. But I can recognize a use case where it's not the right tool for the job. JPA is great to implement simple or complex use-cases involving relatively few entities forming an object graph. To insert a massive amount of rows in a single table, especially if they can simply be extracted from another table, a SQL query is both simpler and much faster. Anyway, if you have 100 identical fields in two distinct entities, then you have a design issue. Most of them should probably grouped in reusable embeddable POJOs, or in associated entities.

Comment: @JBNizet if you don't know the answer, it's fine to say you don't know. When I provide advice to others, answering their actual question is first priority and giving them a better way to do it is second. Providing personal opinion over solution is not very helpful and not very insightful, given each person who posts a question has different constraints and circumstances at work. I can do whatever I want at home. This is not my home. This is a client who clearly didn't think things through and I'm asking for a solution based on their needs, not mine.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. And yes, I do try my best to provide what I think is the best solution, even if the OP might not have thought about that solution. If you haven't noticed, I have answered 12,784 questions here, including 2200 about Hibernate and 1046 about JPA. I think I now know how to use StackOverflow, thank you. You apparently haven't read the last part of my comment, where I strongly advise you, if you won't use SQL, to refactor your entities into reusable embeddable POJOs.

Comment: @JBNizet  That wasn't a comment, it was a suggestion. And a passive aggressive one at that. Every dev's environment is a specific fingerprint, that given management in a company or office has a distinct fingerprint. When a fellow dev asks a question, assuming they are in total control of the environment isn't very helpful. Assisting in providing an answer for their environment-specific solution is. And how could someone navigate through the sarcasm and get to your solution? You just admitted as much. Notice how useful SO is when we start with the assistance and end with our opinion.

Comment: can you use this, read first object , use a data mapper to convert into 2nd object , save second object , this approach gives you benefit of having two independent entities and not messing up by writing the sql for first object and save for other in same code

Comment: @vihar thank you for this approach, after using second object conversion and sbjavateam's answer, I was able to successfully complete this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Employees and Workforce almoust the same you can use hibernate inheritance  . Add copy constructor and resave entity.But it might not to help if you have different constraints or id  generator  (might be a case when Employees already exists with Workforce ids ).
Simple case it's just create Employees from Workforce and save created object via

```
employee = new Employees(w.firstName, w.lastName, w.dept, w.phone);
Employees.saveAndFlush(employee);
```

in this case you create new Employees and repository saves it correct. Maybe after save newEmployees (copy of Workforce ) you should delete old Workforce

Comment: Thank you kindly, sir. I tip my hat.